# add html to fieldset

Tags: 7, theming, commerce, forms

I try to customize fieldset ABC that are inside drupal commerce checkout page.
Markup looks like this

```
<fieldset>
 <legend>ABC</legend>
 <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
  <div class="form-item"></div>
  <div class="form-item"></div>
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

I would like to put some additional code directly inside fieldset and then also some other html directly inside form-item elements. 
Question> What should I do to achieve that? I found this page https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_fieldset/7 would it be of any help? Thank you.

images
[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change it using `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`.

```
// Replace FORM_ID with commerce checkout form id
function hook_form_FORM_ID_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['fieldset_item']['mymarkup'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => 'My Markup Here.',
  );
}
```

Comment: HI, this has no effect on my form. Where should be the markup visible? I try to dmp the form but I can not see 'markup'

Comment: `mymarkup` is the new element which you will be insert and you have to set `#weight` for adding it in middle of the form otherwise it will appear last.

Comment: Hi,if I put your code inside custommodule and replace hook_form... with test_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter (test is name of my module), then all fieldsets should have 'My Markup Here.' somewhere in their markup right? But they dont, even after flushing cache. And dmp($form) does not show any 'fieldset_item' element, only #type fieldset. What I am missing here? Thank you.

Comment: `fieldset_item` is the key for fieldset element. It will add the item in existing fieldset.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, however as I said I can not see any changes.

Comment: I think issue with form_id. Can you please confirm if form_id is okay?

Comment: Hi,I could make it work on specific fieldset by adding $form['account']['fieldset_item']['mymarkup'] = array(... Now the markup shows inside 'fieldset-wrapper' as last item. Adding '#weight' => '-10' as you suggested did not help. Question>Would it be possible to display this markup on same html level as 'fieldset-wrapper'? If not, is there any mistake with weight? Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Change `'#weight' => '-10'` to `'#weight' => -10`. (-10 without single quote)

Comment: Tried various variations but still on same position.

Comment: Check the weight of other elements.. how they are sorted..

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with pictures of markup and dpm of fieldset that I want to alter. There is no sign of weight on other elements.

Comment: It seems you have write `['account']['fieldset_item']['mymarkup']`.. If so remove `['fieldset_item']`.

Comment: great, now it works. Why there was a problem and ['fieldset_item'] has to go? Thank you for help and time

Comment: Because it added the ['mymarkup'] under a child and weight was applying under `['fieldset_item']` and not under `['account']`.